# How to connect and read Emails from SMTP Sever using Apache Kafka in Java

Tags: java, email, apache-kafka, smtp, email-client

I am trying to build an API using Kafka in Java, which can read emails.

The Email server/mailbox is going to be on a SMTP server.

Is there any Kafka API which can read emails from SMTP.
Is there any other code reference/API which can be integrated with Kafka to read the emails.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka doesn't have an SMTP protocol bridge, no. It does not "read email". Kafka stores bytes; doesn't matter what format that data represents.

You'd need to have your Java client fetch data from the email server *on its own*, then parse/serialize that data and produce to Kafka.

You may find tools like Apache Camel or NiFi offer SMTP and Kafka connectors, however where you can easily integrate the two.

Comment: Why cant I have both the processes as one single process in one API: First part of the process will use a Java Client API to read from the SMTP server, convert into a key-value record format. Secondly, the Kafka Producer API will then write the key-value to the topic

Comment: You can. That's what I said. I think you misunderstood the answer; the Kafka **broker** does not "read email". External clients do.

Comment: Using apache Camel to read gmail does not work as gmail has recently disabled access by third party apps with less security through IMAP. Is there any alternative to read the gmail or is there any other server from which i can read emails.  I am using below approach : 
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        Endpoint endpoint = context.getEndpoint("imaps://imap.gmail.com?username=******@gmail.com&password=****&debugMode=true");

Comment: I suggest opening a new post as that's unrelated to my answer about Kafka. Gmail has its own Java SDK, last I checked